# Why it's not replacing?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
public class SecretPhrase 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {     
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);      
        String phrase= "Go Team"; //replace phrase with asterisks      
        phrase=phrase.replace("**","****");
        System.out.println(phrase);       
    }
}
```

Why is `phrase` not being replaced with anything? I want the entire String to be full of `*`.

Comment: because there isn't a * present in your input.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, of course it's not; I need some rest obviously. Thx.

Comment: Which part of documentation of `replace` method makes you think that something should be replaced? What results did you expect and why?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of replace function:

```
Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in "ba" rather than "ab".
Parameters:
target The sequence of char values to be replaced
replacement The replacement sequence of char values
Returns:
The resulting string
```